# Changing blob size on HSQLDB with spring datasource

Tags: spring, blob, hsqldb

I am configuring HSQLDB through Spring and C3P0, this creates the database for me if it doesn't exist.

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb/mydb" />
        <property name="user" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

However, I would like to initialize the BLOB size to 8kb instead of the 32kb default value, is it possible to set the parameter in Spring somehow? I know I can edit later the script file to set `SET FILES LOB SCALE 32` to 8, but I would like it set on Spring/C3P0 if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For new databases, several settings can be included on the URL or as properties.

To change the BLOB block size, add this line:

```
    <property name="hsqldb.lob_file_scale" value="8" />
```

The properties are covered in the Guide:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_file_mem